# Does "vomit" refer to a single heave or an entire episode of vomiting?

Tags: ambiguity

For example, if somebody says "I vomitted four times yesterday" should I assume that they gave four heaves of vomit total, possibly only during a single trip to the bathroom, or should I assume that they went to the bathroom four separate times, possibly giving many heaves each time -- or if both usages are admissible, which is more common?

Comment: It would probably very difficult to provide references for this, or anything that didn't look like an opinion.  My sense, as a native American English speaker, is that *vomit* is used like *eat*.  If I say, "I ate three times yesterday" no one would expect me to mean *I ate three pieces of food*.   But how long do you have to wait before eating the next piece of food becomes a separate "time"?  There's likely no good answer.

Comment: It’s definitely trips not heaves

Comment: @Juhasz I'd say the same thing as a British English speaker. It refers to each _conversation_ with Hughie down the Great White Telephone, not the elements of the conversation!

Comment: Juhasz's answer is a good one. 'Heave' is unarguably punctive, semelfactive rather than durative, but 'vomited four times' very probably defaults to >4 heaves.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Take a look at how the OED deals with the noun *vomit*. It has a series of examples of it employed with the indefinite article, and as plurals. The more recent would seem to suggest a single heave eg. *1794   T. Taylor tr. Pausanias Descr. Greece III. 172   He afterwards threw it up by a vomit.1897   T. C. Allbutt et al. Syst. Med. III. 901   Vomiting in perityphlitis..may occur repeatedly, or there may be only an initial vomit.* The second list 1b, of which there are no recent examples, have it as an uncountable noun, suggesting the substance emitted.

Comment: My own view is that the verb could be employed either way - a single heave, or an episode of heaves.

Comment: @WS2 One wonders sometimes about the methods used by OED. [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vomit%2Ca+vomit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvomit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20vomit%3B%2Cc0) are totally in line with my view on how common 'a vomit' has been for the last 50 years. And looking at actual examples within the samples, most of the count usages are archaic. // The usages of nouns and verbs may differ markedly. 'Scheme' (v) almost always has sinister implications, while 'scheme' (n) is often a laudable enterprise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well I certainly wonder about the methods used by Google ngrams.  What you've shown there is an absurd comparison - if I may say so. The blue line will include both noun and verb instances. The noun sense, I would suggest is relatively rare anyway. It certainly adds nothing to the single heave versus an episode of heaves debate. //I've no idea what your final sentence means.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vomit) defines vomit (verb) for C2 as

**to empty the contents of the stomach through the mouth:**

*He came home drunk and vomited all over the kitchen floor.
She was vomiting (up) blood.*

And for intermediate English as

**to empty the contents of the stomach through the mouth, usually in explosive bursts**

(no application examples provided)

Both definitions make it clear that "vomit" refers to the ACT of emptying the stomach, regardless of the quantity of heaves ("bursts" in the intermediate definition) required to do so.

Comment: I wonder what the advanced definition would be? Yes, the act of emptying the stomach where act can be made up of various heaves.

Comment: @Lambie well, C2 is the highest possible level in the CEFR, so I guess that it makes the first definition the advanced one LOL

Comment: If *to empty* in these definitions is interpreted as *to empty completely*, then they don't seem to quite fit the actual usage. Suppose that one has several such bursts in quick succession, which do not empty the stomach completely, and then, fifteen minute later, a few more bursts in quick succession: one would probably say that one has vomited twice, not once. On the other hand, if *to empty* is interpreted as *to empty partially*, then these definitions do not answer  the question.